# How to return XML from c# to JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My program is giving me an error from jquery. I don't understand why. I works in c# but in jquery it does not

```
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)))
            {
                writer.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
                ser.Serialize(writer, ct);
                XMLContent = sb.ToString();
            }
            return Content(XMLContent, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml);
```

f

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: formobj,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function(req, status, error) {
                alert(req.statusText);
            }
        });
        return false;
```

When I replace

```
return Content(XMLContent, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml);
```

with

```
return Content(XMLContent);
```

and remove

```
dataType: "xml",
```

from jquery it all works.

Comment: In the JQuery Ajax Part the req.statusText value returns OK. So I am stumped on what it could be

Answer (score 2):

One way that could simplify and optimize your ajax a lot, is to use JSON instead of XML.

(unless you really want your result to be XML)

In ASP.Net MVC you can let your Action return Json as result.

```
return Json(new {
    variableName: someData,
    anotherVariableName: someMoreData
});
```

In your Js:

```
$.post(
    'yourActionName',
    optionalData,
    function(d) {
        alert(d.variableName);
        alert(d.anotherVariableName);
    }
);
```

Couldn't be more simple than this :)